# Microsoft Graph API GET onlineMeeting via joinUrl

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

Current using Microsoft Graph API v1.0 to create onlineMeetings via POST /me/events. Reason being, if you create an onlineMeeting directly and add a user in the meeting, it doesn't create a calendar event.

The params I use for that call is:
:isOnlineMeeting => true,
:onlineMeetingProvider => "teamsForBusiness"

Which works great and returns a joinUrl under onlineMeetings.

However, I'd like to pull attendance data from the GET onlineMeeting route to get attendance information since the attendees section of the event only seems to return users that were added to the actual event, not who attended the actual onlineMeeting.

I have tried doing a get request like such:
/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings?$filter=joinWebUrl%20eq%20'https://whateverthejoinurlis'

but the response says it's not a valid filter.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try it in beta version `/beta/me/onlineMeetings?$filter=joinWebUrl%20eq%20'https://whateverthejoinurlis'`. You can also get the attendeereport using `beta/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/{meetingId}/attendeeReport` as specified in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#http-request)

Comment: See if it helps.

Comment: Does the above helped?

Comment: The above helped, however, since a beta route is subject to change, hopefully they bring the functionality to the v1 branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @Shiva Keshav Varma comments

Try it in beta version

```
/beta/me/onlineMeetings?$filter=joinWebUrl%20eq%20'https://whateverthejoinurlis
```

You can also get the attendeereport using `beta/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/{meetingId}/attendeeReport` as specified in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#http-request).

Comment: Already in the v1.0, you can request without 'beta'